# Android: Which Layout?

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout, grid-layout

I want to create a ListView row which looks like this:

```
aaaa bbbb ............. c d e
aaaa bbbb ............. c d e
aaaa bbbb ............. c d e
```

where:
aaaa & bbbb are fixed size columns
.... is a variable size text string
c, d & e are images 30x30 pixels each

Which is the best layout to use for this? What I want is for the .... text string to use up all remaining space but all other columns to remain fixed width.

I tried using LinearLayout but couldn't get c, d and e to align unless I specified a specific size for the ...... but I don't want to specify a specific size for the ......

GridLayout almost did the trick but then it appears like this:

```
aaaa bbbb ............. c d          e
aaaa bbbb ............. c d          e
aaaa bbbb ............. c d          e
```

Here's my GridLayout XML but I am not committed to use GridLayout. I would also like to avoid having to set the column widths at runtime if possible as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="6"

    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lv_artist"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Artist"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lv_album"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Album"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lv_tune"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Tune"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ibAddPlaylist"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/clipboard30x30grey" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ibLikeHate"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/unchecked" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivPlay"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/play_30x30" />    
</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`layout_gravity` and `layout_weight` will do the trick, see Android's [Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html) or [Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) on `LinearLayout`.

The following code should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lv_artist"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Artist"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lv_album"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Album"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <!--
      ~ Use android:layout_weight so that this view will take up all the space
      ~ remaining when no other view has specifed its weight.
     -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lv_tune"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Tune"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <!-- 
      ~ android:gravity is for the gravity in the View itself, while
      ~ android:layout_gravity is for the gravity of the View in it's
      ~ ViewGroup(container), in this case it may not be what you intended to
      ~ do, so I removed it for you.
     -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ibAddPlaylist"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/clipboard30x30grey" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ibLikeHate"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/unchecked" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivPlay"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/play_30x30" />    
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you. That did the trick. Very simple too. Its been a while since I played around with the layouts in any detail but last time I had to resort to calculating and setting columns widths in the code which was a pain - that was with GridLayouts though. I've accepted your answer - thank you for the quick applicable answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `LinearLayout` using `android:weightSum` on it and `android:layout_weight` on its child `Views`?

Comment: `weightSum` is completely **useless**. Android calculates it **automatically**.

Comment: I know. What I was trying to get to is maybe have the fixed columns have a fixed width with not weights, and have the expanding one have one. The answer by @DreaminginCode is what I had in mind.